# How can I define the change address of a transaction using createrawtransaction?

Tags: bitcoind, raw-transaction, change

This question is almost the opposite of [How to find the change / sender address given a txid?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/28182/how-to-find-the-change-sender-address-given-a-txid)

If I am making a transaction using `createrawtransaction` how can I define the change (sender) address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Bitcoin, change is a normal output which sends the remaining money to one of your addresses. When creating a transaction with `createrawtransaction`, you have to add change output manually (just like any other output), otherwise that money would go to the miners.

Comment: i came with the same question because im not sure how to define the 2nd output. the example shows the output as a single object, not an array.